# Off-shell vs half off-shell vs fully off-shell $T$-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, scattering, definition, s-matrix-theory

I know what are on-shell particles, but I want to know what are off-shell, and half off-shell, and fully off-shell states? and how we decide to consider one of these states in evaluating $T$-Matrix?

Comment: $\uparrow$ source?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I faced with these terminology in few-body calculations (Nuclear physics).

Comment: half off-shell could correspond to partially on-shell currents, for example a three-point vertex with two legs on-shell.

Comment: Thank you, but I think it may be related to the singularity of T-Matrix.